# HDMI Audio output not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi

When I plug in the HDMI,the video works fine, but the sound does not. I've poked around and I think that the HDMI audio may not be being detected.

When I ran aplay -l:

> **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC663 Analog [ALC663 Analog]   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1:
>   ALC663 Digital [ALC663 Digital]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0:
>   subdevice #0

I've tried installing the pulse audio control and going to the "configurations" tab, but nothing there mentions HDMI.

I've tried reinstalling the alsa mixer and unmuting everything. No dice.

I've tried turning it off and on again. No dice

I'm running Dual Graphics NVidia (proprietary driver) and the open source driver for the Intel N56VZ (Don't know if thats relevant, but there you go)

Comment: did you try unplugging and plugging it (the HDMI cable) back in?

Answer (score 0):

Just plug it in with the output settings open, and if you see it there click on it and close the window. It should work, because it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

HDMI output from devices such broadband set top boxes seem to output audio.  I am not remotely convinced that computer graphics cards do this as well.  Please check with the graphics card manufacturer to determine if yours is supposed to do that.  Nothing is nearly as difficult to accomplish as the impossible.